# Merge 2 tables into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a very simplified example but i hope you get the idea.

We have a parent child relationship

Parent

```
Id (number)
name
```

Child

```
Parent_id (= id in parent)
Recno
name
```

Parents

```
1,Alison
2,Mary
3,Helen
```

children

```
1,1,john
1,2,mike
1,3,fred
2,1,steve
2,2,martin
2,3,sam
3,1,maurice
3,2,pete
3,3,matt
```

Need to merge these tables together and insert into another table

Result

```
Columns = Id,parent_name,name_1,name_2,name_3
1,Alison,john,mike,fred
2,Mary,steve,martin,sam
3,Helen,maurice,pete,matt
```

Any help gratefully received

Comment: Is good practice to show what querys have you done

Comment: Are there always precisely 3 children for every parent?

Comment: There are always a fixed number of children yes.

Answer (score 0):

Try string aggregation function STRING_AGG:

```
SELECT A.Parent_ID, B.parent_name,
    PARSENAME(STRING_AGG(A.name, '.'),1) AS name_1,
    PARSENAME(STRING_AGG(A.name , '.'),2) AS name_2,
    PARSENAME(STRING_AGG(A.name, '.'),3) AS name_3
FROM children A
INNER JOIN parent B ON A.Parent_id = B.Id
GROUP BY A.Parent_ID, B.parent_name
```

Comment: I can see how that would work if i just wanted to display them but I need to insert them into another table as individual columns.  How would that work?

Comment: And i realised I missed this, I need to include columns from the parent table as well. (now added above)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PIVOT

```
DECLARE @Parent TABLE (Id INT, name VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @Parent
VALUES 
(1,'Alison'),
(2,'Mary'),
(3,'Helen')


DECLARE @Child TABLE (Parent_id INT, Recno INT, name VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @Child VALUES
(1,1,'john'),
(1,2,'mike'),
(1,3,'fred'),
(2,1,'steve'),
(2,2,'martin'),
(2,3,'sam'),
(3,1,'maurice'),
(3,2,'pete'),
(3,3,'matt')

INSERT INTO AnotherTable (Id, parent_name, name_1, name_2, name_3)
SELECT 
    PVT.Id, PVT.parent_name, PVT.[1] name_1, PVT.[2] name_2, PVT.[3] name_3 
FROM 
    ( SELECT P.Id, P.name as parent_name, C.Recno, C.name as child_name FROM @Parent AS P
        INNER JOIN @Child AS C ON P.Id = C.Parent_id ) AS SRC
PIVOT (MAX(SRC.child_name) FOR SRC.Recno IN ([1],[2],[3])) PVT
```

Result:

```
Id          name       name_1      name_2    name_3   
----------- ---------- ----------- --------- -----------
1           Alison     john        mike      fred
2           Mary       steve       martin    sam
3           Helen      maurice     pete      matt
```

Comment: Thanks i had been looking at pivots.  How  would i use that query to insert into the result table?

Comment: You can write 'insert into' with table name and columns over the select.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a go.

Comment: In my "real" code I have duplicate column names on parent and child tables and I get
The column "my_id" was specified multiple times for PVT.

Comment: Then, you should change the inner join part to subquery with only necessary columns.

Answer (score 0):

you can use create a table using a SELECT query and PIVOT like below:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
   AS 
 (
 SELECT PVT.Id AS ParentId, PVT.name as ParentName, PVT.[1] AS name_1,PVT.[2] AS 
 name_2,PVT.[3] AS name_3 
FROM Parents AS P
INNER JOIN Childs AS C ON P.Id = C.Parent_id
PIVOT (MAX(C.name) FOR C.Recno IN ([1],[2],[3])) PVT
 );
```